# How to prevent *ngFor from updating the DOM in Angular 4?

Tags: javascript, angular, ngfor

In angular 4, I'm using *ngFor to show some images

```
<div  *ngFor='let image of images;let i = index'>
    <img  [src]="'/assets/Images/'+image+'.png'" *ngIf="!tohide(i,0);">
</div>
```

After *ngFor is done for the first time, I wish to remove a specific image via *ngIf, without changing the array 'images'. The problem is whenever I removed an image with my function 'tohide', *ngFor bind again to the 'images' and update the set of images.

> In other words, is there a way to force *ngFor to not to listen to the array 'images' occasionally?

Comment: What does your tohide() function do? can you post the code of the same

Comment: Can't you modify the array before rendering items?

Comment: what is in the tohide() function?

Comment: You should mutate your array rather than creating a new array. If you will then Angular will re render the array. Can you paste you ts code here then I can help better.

Answer (score 5):

`*ngFor` has a track by function by default, in your case, you want to override it.

```
<div  *ngFor='let image of images;let i = index; trackBy: myTrackByFunction'>
  <img  [src]="'/assets/Images/'+image+'.png'" *ngIf="!tohide(i,0);">
</div>
```

In your TS

```
myTrackByFunction(index, item) {
  return index; // or item.id, if your image has an ID
}
```

For more information, [see this web page](https://netbasal.com/angular-2-improve-performance-with-trackby-cc147b5104e5)

Answer (score 1):

u can specify another property i your array named "removed": False and then use this:

```
<div  *ngFor='let image of images;let i = index'>
<img  [src]="'/assets/Images/'+image+'.png'" [hidden]="i.removed">
```

whenever u want to remove an item without really remove it from array just set "removed" property to True.

Answer (score 0):

You can use following as one of the appropriate ways to solve this:

1. You can track remove status of each image object by adding a property called `removed` set to false initially.
2. You then implement a filter (as explained [here](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/filter-in-angular-4/)) with `*ngFor` to filter out the images.
3. When you remove an image, set the `removed` flag to true. This will filter out the removed image.

Edit: the `trackBy` is another parameter for *ngFor which you can use instead of developing a separate filter. The filter would give you additional control and features if you need so.

Hope this helps!